# Deployment packaging for open-webkit-sharp libraries

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, open-webkit-sharp

I have created an application which uses open webkit sharp library to show some web pages.

But while deploying I am facing the issue of moving so many files and folders.

So what are my options here?

1. Installing dlls into the GAC. I might consider this as an options, but will this option be helpful as I might need to install  many dlls.
2. Package all files and folders into a folder and load all required dlls from this folder at runtime. Keeping all this into a same folder will help me to move open-web-kit-sharp library  from one production server to another.

What are my other options? Am I thinking in right direction or do I need to include something else into consideration?